# General network error pop up when i go to (promote) active directory (Domain Controller) on my Win16 server

Tags: active-directory

I am running 2016 Server standard. I installed AD on the host and have a VM running DHCP as the guest. Currently we are running an external DNS Server & we are on a workgroup. After installed AD and was getting ready to promote, the following error spawned: General Network Error

Event viewer doesn't say much.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: General Network Errors usually relate to either a misconfiguration, bad drivers, or a duplicate IP (either real, or detected).  At this point, we would need more information about the actual server to even begin to guess.

Answer (score 3):

**Domain Controllers should NEVER use DHCP.**

Due to the reliance on the domain-controller's DNS entries... the simple fact is that the entries cannot be assigned dynamically.  They must be static... and thus, the server itself must be static.

Comment: The server indeed does have a static address friend.

Comment: So... what is the "VM running DHCP"... and how does it fit into the equation?

Comment: Manager didn't want DHCP server & AD on the same "computer" so he suggested putting the DHCP server in a VM on the same box. I said, "OK". DHCP is not active yet but he wants to have AD/DNS on the Host computer & DHCP on the Guest VM. Host & VM both have static addresses. Thanks

Comment: It is an interesting setup, & I guess I noted the VM comment just to give you a thorough "environment" on that particular computer.

Comment: I find it more confusing than helpful... as it doesn't relate even slightly to the issue.  It would be like saying... "the server's chassis is blue."

Comment: I just added that info being it could be a contributor to the error i am receiving. The VM is bridged to the hosts NIC, and the error I am getting is a "General Network Error" so it is a variable in this equation. Relevant or not, not sure. But thanks you.

Comment: I have posted the error at the following link:
https://imgur.com/a/pOXwN

note: My Host has a static IP
Thanks